# Why declare packages in root level package.json of monorepo - lerna

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lerna

I am working with a monorepo that uses lerna. This repo declares `file:` protocol packages at the root package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "moduleA": "file:packages/moduleA,
    "moduleB": "file:packages/moduleB
}
```

The lerna.json at the root of this monorepo has the standard default packages folder glob pattern:

```
{
    "packages": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

So why do this? I do not see anywhere in the [official documentation](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#lernajson) that mentions explicitly adding the `leaf packages` that lerna manages to the package.json:

> The packages config in lerna.json is a list of globs that match directories containing a package.json, which is how lerna recognizes "leaf" packages (vs the "root" package.json, which is intended to manage the dev dependencies and scripts for the entire repo).

If lerna is "aware" (`learn ls`) of the `leaf packages` in the `packages` folder, why explicitly declare the `leaf packages` as dependencies in the root package.json?

*Note that the team I am working on manages a couple monorepos, one monorepo has no dependencies in the root package.json but this monorepo does. Thus, there is intention behind it, and I am trying to figure out what that intention is*.

Comment: Probably because that's what [the official documentation](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#lernajson) shows. You can omit it, but why leave people guessing instead of just being explicit about your paths, configs, etc.? Easier for future devs to immediately see what's going on.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I do not see anywhere in the official documentation that mentions explicitly adding the packages that lerna is manages to the root package.json

Comment: Then you may have forgot to read the section text for the part I linked to. Scroll down a little bit to the paragraphs "_The packages config_ [...]" and "_By default, lerna initializes the packages list as_ [...]"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes I read this, thank you. I think we might just have different perspectives slightly at the moment. See the specific language in the documentation you have pointed me to furthers my conundrum: Why explicitly add packages that lerna manages to the root package.json.dependencies property? The documentation even says the root package.json is just for devDependencies

Comment: Hm, but those dependencies are not lerna-specific, that's just one of the various patterns that `npm` allows you specify code dependencies in. What makes you think they're only there for lerna, rather than for code that relies on those dependencies for actual functionality?

Comment: I must need attend to the phrasing of my question than, the dependencies in my question "moduleA", "moduleB" are for code that relies on those dependencies for actual functionality. In this monorepo I am working on leaf level packages rely on each other and I guess this is the answer to my question as well.

Comment: Do build scripts or similar have dependent code to these packages? You might want to be able to use scripts you have created in one of your packages in your other ones as well (custom eslint plugins that you haven't put into their own package for example)

Comment: @Narigo Well there are build scripts that will relatively (../../) go to root and into the root node_modules to execute that script command but I am not sure I am properly answering your question

Comment: I don't know enough about your project, so it's hard to guess for me. I would assume that some build steps or scripts in root may have dependencies and thus need it. Otherwise: Did you try deleting the dependencies and all scripts still work? May also be an inconsistency